# Redirection at save button

Tags: list, redirect, save

I have a scenario where the users are required to add an item to a specific list.
and then they should be redirected to another list automatically.
the issue I'm having with the scripts I used was that the items are not being saved at the original list!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetParameterValues(param) { 
        var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) { var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
        if (urlparam[0] == param) {
            return urlparam[1]; 
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // for Save button. You need to change it. 
        var button = $('input[name$="SaveItem"]');
        button.removeAttr("onclick");
        button.click(function () {
            var listUrl = "/sites/test1/Lists/testlist/NewForm.aspx";
            var itemId = GetParameterValues("ID");
            var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
            var aspForm = $("form[id=aspnetForm]");
            var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
            var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
            var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, listUrl + "/EditForm.aspx?ID=" + itemId);
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a SharePoint form, in the url for NewItem.aspx or whatever your input form is.  If you add "?Source=" it will automatically redirect there after saving.

For Instance:

```
https://<farmurl>/sites/<sitecollection>/Lists/<listname>/forms/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://www.google.com
```

Will redirect to google after closing the form via save or cancel.

Another option is to have a custom save button

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton  RedirectUrl="http://urlhere" runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton"/>
```